# Is there a way I can select the instances in the protocol column and turn them into columns?

Tags: r

I am trying to process a SYN flood attack dataset and I need to pull out each of the instances, Like TCP, SSH, ARP, IEC, IMCP, etc and turn them to columns. Can someone help me out?

[SYN Flood attack dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFVlv.png)

Comment: why is this code giving me error?                                                                                                 Total <- select(filter(QMdata,QMdata$Protocol==TCP))
Error: object 'TCP' not found

Answer (score 0):

You may use the **dplyr** package to do this, with the functions **gather** to pivot the dataset **from a wide format to long format** or **spread** to convert the dataset **from a long format to a wide format**.
By the term **instance** you used, I understood you are talking about pivoting rows to columns. So I suggest you to use the **spread** function. If you want, attach more information over the original data and I may help you more effectively.

Comment: Total <- spread(QMdata, QMdata$protocol, QMdata$info)
Error: Must extract column with a single subscript.
x The subscript `var` has size 0 but must be size 1.